# How to increase download timeout setting in Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, gae-eclipse-plugin

I'm having trouble downloading the Google App Engine plugin for Eclipse.  Specifically, it times out when it reaches this file:

```
com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.2.1.0_2.1.0.v201010280102.jar
```

I'm able to download it manually, but downloading pauses for a very long time right before finishing (???)
I figure if I can increase the download timeout, I can get the installation to work, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all `URLConnection`-based provider are managed by system properties, which are listed in:

[**Networking Properties**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html)

In particular, the property **`sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout`** (set by default to 30 seconds) can be changed and increased in an **[`eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659)**.
You can also try with `sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout`. See this [SO answer for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808487/how-to-set-a-connection-timeout-when-using-jaxrpc-ri-web-services-client).

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse **p2**(the provisioning manager) uses **ECF** to download the content from remote site. There are some system property to set the timeout value of ECF.

[ECF timeout setting](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/TransportDebugging)

Those options should be since Eclipse 3.6, the default transfer should be httpclient implementation.

If you are adding these options to a commandline, they need to follow the argument '-vmargs'