# How to fix an Eclipse 3.6 plugin installation?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, gae-eclipse-plugin

I tried to install the Google App Engine plugin in Eclipse (Version 3.6 Helios) via `Install New Software...`, but the download never finished because it kept timing out.  I then tried to install the plugin via the "dropin" method as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202592/how-to-increase-download-timeout-setting-in-eclipse-3-6-helios/4202692#4202692).

No success.

I think the GAE plugin was partially installed by my initial attempts, so Eclipse no longer accepts the  dropin method.  The Google plugin shows up under installed items, but it doesn't look too healthy:

[image]

My best option seems to uninstall the GAE plugin and start over using the dropin approach, but how can I do this?  Any other solutions?

This is on Windows XP.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it would really help if you specify which version of Eclipse you are using as each version has its quirks.

Comment: use this: http://ondemand.yoxos.com/geteclipse/start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by installing Eclipse *for Java **EE** Developers*

Answer (score 3):

I had to manually added the plugin to \configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\
under bundles.info, after copying the plugin into the plugin folder.

Not sure why, but it did work.