# Set Time out for webservices with oracle weblogic server 10.3 (java)

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to set time out error whenever web service response will be delayed with below lines of code-

```
serviceStub._setProperty("weblogic.wsee.transport.connection.timeout", String.valueOf(timeoutSeconds));
BindingInfo bindingInfo = (BindingInfo)serviceStub._getProperty("weblogic.wsee.binding.BindingInfo");
bindingInfo.setTimeout(timasseoutSeconds);
```

But it’s not working.

Server Used – Oracle Weblogic server 10.3

Type of Web service – JAX-RPC

Please reply, if someone has solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of timeout (See [What is the difference between connection and read timeout for sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069382/what-is-the-difference-between-connection-and-read-timeout-for-sockets))

> `weblogic.wsee.transport.connection.timeout`
>
> Specifies, in seconds, how long a client application that is attempting to invoke a Web service waits to make a connection. After the specified time elapses, if a connection hasn't been made, the attempt times out.
>
> `weblogic.wsee.transport.read.timeout`
>
> Specifies, in seconds, how long a client application waits for a response from a Web service it is invoking. After the specified time elapses, if a response hasn't arrived, the client times out.

You should set sensible values for both. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11736871/33622) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need: weblogic.wsee.transport.read.timeout

Got that from here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13760/client.htm